# "Dereference" var in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code in C# that uses a structure as such:

```
ArrayList addrs = new ArrayList();
byte[] addr = new byte[8];
while (oneWire.Search_GetNextDevice(addr))
{
    addrs.Add(addr);
}
```

In this example, every element in the `ArrayList` is the same as the last device that was found because it would appear as though `addr` is passed out by reference and I am simply copying that reference into the `ArrayList`.

Is there any way to "Dereference" `addr` to only extract it's value?

It's also possible my assessment of the situation is incorrect, if that appears to be the case, please let me know

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the declaration of the var addr and  of it's class/struct.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it's a byte[8]

Comment: Right, `byte[]` is not a struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need something like `addrs.Add(addr.Clone());` to create a copy (or clone) of `addr` to put in your list.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it! :) I will accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me.

Answer (score 6):

If `addr` is a class variable (and not a struct) it would figure.

In that case `Search_GetNextDevice()` would be filling the same instance over and over.

You might be able to solve it with something like

```
byte[] addr = new byte[8];
while (oneWire.Search_GetNextDevice(addr))
{
   addrs.Add(addr);
   addr = new byte[8];
}
```

---

updated with the `byte[]` info

Comment: That's right; however, if the OP is in control of the `Search_GetNextDevice` method I would redesign it to yield a new object every time instead of filling an existing one: `while (oneWire.TryGetNextDevice(out var addr)) { addrs.Add(addr); }`. Also, if possible, I would use a typed list (`List<byte[]>`). But if coding against an existing API, this might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

if addr is a structure, then there are multiple problems can arise.

First of all, addr will not change and if it has to change then you need to declare `Search_GetNextDevice` as a ref.

If you are changing values of `addr.something` in `Search_GetNextDevice`, then you will notsee those values in the copy you have.They will be lost since structures are passed by value to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to array, then loop that copy:

```
 ArrayList addrs = new ArrayList();
        while (oneWire.Search_GetNextDevice(addr.ToArray((whateverTypeYourItemsHave[])typeof(whateverTypeYourItemsHave))))
        {
            addrs.Add(addr);
        }
```

Or better if you know what the items in your list are, use generic list. Better to read, less error prone:

```
List<whateverYourItemTypeIs> addrs = new List<whateverYourItemTypeIs>();
        while (oneWire.Search_GetNextDevice(addr.ToArray()))
        {
            addrs.Add(addr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference types, you ultimately have to clone the object. There is not a built-in way for most classes, though there is for an array, which the Accepted Answer shows appropriately.

One option (for those not using an array) is to serialize and deserialize from a format like JSON or MessagePack. This works for some types. (a POCO class can be serialized to JSON, and can IEnumerables). You can use a method like this to clone an object via serialization:

```cs
internal static class CloneHelper
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T item) where T : class, new()
    {
        var asString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item);
        var newObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(asString);
        if (newObject is null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong in serialization");
        }
        return newObject;
    }
}
```

If you want to simulate C# 9 record cloning functionality (`with` keyword), you can do something like this (probably don't do this in production).

```cs
internal static class CloneHelper
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T item, object? with = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        var asString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item);
        var newObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(asString);
        if (newObject is null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong in serialization");
        }
        if (with is not null)
        {
            foreach (var property in with.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var val = property.GetValue(with);
                typeof(T).GetProperties()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == property.Name 
                        && ReferenceEquals(x.PropertyType, property.PropertyType))
                    ?.SetValue(newObject, val);
            }
        }
        return newObject;
    }
}
```

However, serialization and reflection are both slow and not 100% type-safe, so don't do this in performance critical or safety critical situation.